# What is https://i.instagram.com/api/v1

Tags: rest, api, instagram, instagram-api

I am digging into Instagram APIs and find out a URL `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1` which used by many git repos(some are recently updated) but when I go to Instagram there is no such url available there. Can anyone guide me what is the use of this url and how I can use it because when I hit

```
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/
```

by POSTMAN i got below message

```json
{
    "message": "Your version of Instagram is out of date. Please upgrade your app to log in to Instagram.",
    "status": "fail",
    "error_type": "needs_upgrade"
}
```

One more thing. I am with my friend who work in android he has done reverse engineering on a app which use for increase followers and that app is also using same endpoints and working on that app.

Comment: Sounds like that API version is *deprecated* and no longer in use/should not be used anymore.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API. its recently updated.

Comment: As it says there: *"This is Instagram's private API."* Basically, you're on your own if you poke around there, and in fact Instagram would rather you not.

Answer (score 4):

It's November 2021, and somehow the API `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1` still works, but I believe they have changed the way you use it.

**NOTE: The given information is just for educational purposes**

Let's take the `user/{user_id}/info` endpoint of this API, which returns basic information about the `user_id`.

The URL with this endpoint would be

```
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/176702683/info/
```

If you paste this link into your browser you'll get the following message

```json
{"message":"useragent mismatch","status":"fail"}
```

This means that API must be called via mobile user-agent. *read more about user-agent [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent)*

We can solve this problem by providing a **mobile** user-agent string.

#### Using python `requests` library

```py
!pip install requests
import requests
URL = https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/176702683/info/
headers = {'User-Agent':'Instagram 76.0.0.15.395 Android (24/7.0; 640dpi; 1440x2560; samsung; SM-G930F; herolte; samsungexynos8890; en_US; 138226743)'} 
# samsung mobile user-agent

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

Output:

```json
{
    "user": {
        "username": "marcelotwelve",
        "pk": 176702683,
        "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fzrh3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/233796637_544571223333074_8761964745157634211_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150\\u0026_nc_ht=instagram.fzrh3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\\u0026_nc_cat=1\\u0026_nc_ohc=Cfk2kHCxgbIAX_vgNjn\\u0026edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA\\u0026ccb=7-5\\u0026oh=00_AT-tuXbAbsIkvmJqm_akQS__UPDtEXZxZChx2lO-9Wb0FQ\\u0026oe=62A8115E\\u0026_nc_sid=a9513d"
    },
    "status": "ok"
}
```

**NOTE: Please be aware of how you use it**

Answer (score 3):

It is actually an API, that you can only use from your phone application, thats why it say it needs upgrade. you can download an addon for chrome / firefox to switch user agents, and after that you will be able to see the content.

It's worth checking there is lots of info about any user on insa

Answer (score 1):

this response is a default error caused by having no cookie set

inspect [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/), you can see a redirect first (this way they fill initial cookies set for you). copy paste it to postman and try again