# Error when scraping Instagram media, by adding at the end of URL (?__a=1)

Tags: instagram, screen-scraping, instagram-api

Sometimes when trying to scrape Instagram media, by adding at the end of the URL (?__a=1)

EX:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CP-Kws6FoRS/?__a=1

The response returned

```json
{
    "__ar": 1,
    "error": 1357004,
    "errorSummary": "Sorry, something went wrong",
    "errorDescription": "Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.",
    "payload": null,
    "hsrp": {
        "hblp": {
            "consistency": {
                "rev": 1005622141
            }
        }
    },
    "lid": "7104767527440109183"
}
```

Why is this response returned and what should I do to fix this? Also, did we have another way to get the video and photo URL?

Answer (score 31):

I solved this problem by adding `&__d=dis` to the query string at the end of the URL, like so: `https://www.instagram.com/p/CFr6G-whXxp/?__a=1&__d=dis`

Comment: Adding onto this: From a quick test, it looks to me like `__d` just needs to be set to a non-empty value to get it working again.

Comment: This answer stop working for me. May be you have new solution @nasser? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Where did you come with this link and parameters?

Answer (score 6):

I believe I may found a workaround using:

- `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username={username}` to get the user's info and recent posts. `data.user` from the response is the same as `graphql.user` from `https://i.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1`.
- Extract the media id from `<meta property="al:ios:url" content="instagram://media?id={media_id}">` in the HTML response of `https://instagram.com/p/{post_shortcode}`.
- `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/media/{media_id}/info` using the extracted media id to get the same response as `https://instagram.com/p/{post_shortcode}/?__a=1`.

A couple important of points:

- The `user-agent` used in the script is important. I found the one Firefox generated when re-sending requests in the dev tools returned the `"Sorry, something went wrong"` error.
- This solution uses cookies from your Firefox profile. You need to sign in to Instagram in Firefox before running this script. You can switch Firefox to Chrome if you'd like.

```py
cookiejar = browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name='instagram.com')
```

Here's the full script. Let me know if this is helpful!

```py
import os
import pathlib
import string
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import bs4 as bs
import browser_cookie3
from google.auth.transport import requests
import requests

# setup.
username = "<username>"
output_path = "C:\\some\\path"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; GM1903 Build/PKQ1.190110.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/75.0.3770.143 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 103.1.0.15.119 Android (28/9; 420dpi; 1080x2260; OnePlus; GM1903; OnePlus7; qcom; sv_SE; 164094539)"
}


def download_post_media(post: dict, media_list: list, number: int):
    output_filename = f"{output_path}/{username}"
    if not os.path.isdir(output_filename):
        os.mkdir(output_filename)
    post_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(post["taken_at_timestamp"])) + timedelta(hours=5)
    output_filename += f"/{username}_{post_time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}_{post['shortcode']}_{number}"
    current_media_json = media_list[number - 1]
    if current_media_json['media_type'] == 1:
        media_type = "image"
        media_ext = ".jpg"
        media_url = current_media_json["image_versions2"]['candidates'][0]['url']
    elif current_media_json['media_type'] == 2:
        media_type = "video"
        media_ext = ".mp4"
        media_url = current_media_json["video_versions"][0]['url']
    output_filename += media_ext
    response = send_request_get_response(media_url)
    with open(output_filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)


def send_request_get_response(url):
    cookiejar = browser_cookie3.firefox(domain_name='instagram.com')
    return requests.get(url, cookies=cookiejar, headers=headers)


# use the /api/v1/users/web_profile_info/ api to get the user's information and its most recent posts.
profile_api_url = f"https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username={username}"
profile_api_response = send_request_get_response(profile_api_url)
# data.user is the same as graphql.user from ?__a=1.
timeline_json = profile_api_response.json()["data"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]
for post in timeline_json["edges"]:
    # get the HTML page of the post.
    post_response = send_request_get_response(f"https://instagram.com/p/{post['node']['shortcode']}")
    html = bs.BeautifulSoup(post_response.text, 'html.parser')
    # find the meta tag containing the link to the post's media.
    meta = html.find(attrs={"property": "al:ios:url"})
    media_id = meta.attrs['content'].replace("instagram://media?id=", "")
    # use the media id to get the same response as ?__a=1 for the post.
    media_api_url = f"https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/media/{media_id}/info"
    media_api_response = send_request_get_response(media_api_url)
    media_json = media_api_response.json()["items"][0]
    media = list()
    if 'carousel_media_count' in media_json:
        # multiple media post.
        for m in media_json['carousel_media']:
            media.append(m)
    else:
        # single media post.
        media.append(media_json)
    media_number = 0
    for m in media:
        media_number += 1
        download_post_media(post['node'], media, media_number)
```

Comment: More info about this API (`i.instagram.com`) can be found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452544/what-is-https-i-instagram-com-api-v1

Comment: `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/media/{media_id}/info` -  doesn't work for me. It returns `{"message":"useragent mismatch","status":"fail"}`

Comment: I can confirm this is working with javascript fetch function. This will return with above message when access through browser directly.

Comment: @AmitSharma Use a mobile user-agent as in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

User-Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; GM1903 Build/PKQ1.190110.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/75.0.3770.143 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 103.1.0.15.119 Android (28/9; 420dpi; 1080x2260; OnePlus; GM1903; OnePlus7; qcom; sv_SE; 164094539)
```

/?__a=1 alternative endpoint; 
BUT You should put user-agent for using this endpoint. 
[https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username={username}](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=%7Busername%7D)

data.graphql.user = data.user 
give same result

Answer (score 0):

ig modified the method,
used the new method:

```
GET https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/tags/web_info/?tag_name=${tags}
```

next page:

```
POST https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/tags/${tags}/sections/
body: 
{
include_persistent: 0
max_id: ${The last request contained this field}
next_media_ids[]: ${The last request contained this field}
next_media_ids[]: ${The last request contained this field}
page: ${The last request contained this field}
surface: grid
tab: recent
}
```

Comment: how I can get the post (video or image) details using this method?

Answer (score 0):

I have your problem too. I am currently using an alternative solution to find a definitive solution.
I have designed an offline api to convert links to media IDs. To use it, submit a request as follows:
http://api-bot.ir/api/insta/media_id/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CP-Kws6FoRS/
Instead of this link, put any other link, you will receive a media ID. Of course, I emphasize that this is offline, and I can guide you to know the exact number of likes and other post information. So let me know if you need more help. Good luck.