# Error when I scrape Instagram accounts. Adding `?__a=1` to the URL doesn't work anymore. Any clues?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Until 2 days ago, I was able to scrape Instagram accounts by adding `?__a=1` at the end of the URL.

E.g.: `https://www.instagram.com/xavi/?__a=1`

Now, when I do the same thing I get this response:

```json
for (;;);
{
  "__ar": 1,
  "error": 1357004,
  "errorSummary": "Sorry, something went wrong",
  "errorDescription": "Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.",
  "payload": null,
  "hsrp": {
    "hblp": {
      "consistency": {
        "rev": 1005632913
      }
    }
  },
  "lid": "7105412861952089317"
}
```

Maybe Instagram might have done some changes in their API.

Is there any clue on how to scrape user information? Or is there any workaround?

Comment: related? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72467565/error-when-scraping-instagram-media-by-adding-at-the-end-of-url-a-1`

Comment: @QHarr similar, yes. 
Their question is about media/post information. 
Mine is about detailed account information.

Comment: The solution proposed by Mehdi Zamani seems to work fine, it should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 24):

You can use

?__a=1&__d=dis

At the end of your URL

E.g.: https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1&__d=1

Comment: No longer works as of 26 Jan 2024 :(

Anyone has workarounds?

Comment: @wolnavi have you found a workaround?

Comment: @Rees yea i'm using the [curl method](https://www.reddit.com/r/webscraping/comments/19fgptv/comment/kjjy2v7/) now..

Answer (score 0):

I tried different ways and did not get the right answer. For now, use this link to find the right way. I can further guide you to get more information about an ID

https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=user&count=0&query=xavi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cookie then just remove the `ds_user_id` field from cookie
it will work fine